# 360 3D Product Image Rotation using React Native

Tags: react-native, 360-degrees

We're trying to find out if a 360 3D image rotation package for React Native exists for both Android and iOS. (or if it's straight forward without)

e.g. http://www.voidcanvas.com/demo/28823deye/ (thats just a jQuery example)

We're aware that there's things like React 360, and Google VR - however these put YOU in the center of the 360 environment, rather than putting an image sequence in the center - and letting you rotate the object.

Answer (score 0):

currently react native doesn't have such things but you can use webview inside react native and use a javascript library to achive that. or you can implement yours with react native gesture handler